# Is a back massage permitted by opposite gender?

Tags: halal-haram, men-women

If one has tension and stress and backache can one get a massage of the back, shoulders and neck by the opposite gender?

Comment: If the answers below satisfy your query please mark the relevant one as accepted. Else please elaborate on your doubts/questions.

Answer (score 5):

> It was narrated that Ma’qil ibn Yassaar said: the Messenger of Allah
>   said: “For one of you to
>   be stabbed in the head with an iron needle is better for him than that
>   he should touch a woman who is not permissible for him.”
>
> Narrated by al-Tabaraani in al-Kabeer, 486.

Medical treatment by the opposite gender is '*permitted*' during a medical emergency incase a doctor of the same gender isn't available. Islam differentiates between different options in a given situation (eg: choosing the woman over the yet to be born child incase of a medical emergency *when all options have been exhausted*).

Afaik back massages typically are done for non-fatal reasons and it is usually easy to find a masseur of the same gender.